# Why can't a member function require a static constexpr member of the same class to be true?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, requires-clause

I try to have a member function require a static constexpr boolean member to be true. This would be very helpful to DRY a quite complex requirement. And I do not quire get the reason why the compiler won't let me.

Minimal example with slightly less complex requirement:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr bool isInt = std::integral<T>;
    void bar() requires (isInt);
    void goo() requires std::integral<T>;
};

template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::bar() requires (Foo<T>::isInt) // error: out-of-line definition of 'bar' does not match any declaration in 'Foo<T>' x86-64 clang 14.0.0 #1
{
    // ...
}

template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::goo() requires std::integral<T> // ok
{
    // ...
}
```

Is this because `isInt` is declared inside the same class? Or do I have some kind of syntax error?

Comment: Seems like just an msvc problem. clang and gcc happily accept it (as they should).

Comment: @Barry As commented in the code snippet, [Clang currently does not](https://godbolt.org/z/9dsK1seT7). As per [the answer from user17732522](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75035712/440558) it seems to be a bug that is about to be fixed in future releases.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude [As I said, it currently does.](https://godbolt.org/z/GqsWhhMK5)

Comment: @Barry Ah, you're using the *trunk* build of Clang, which is not yet part of a Clang release. Comment updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a question of whether or not your `requires` clauses in the in-class declaration and out-of-class definition are *equivalent* (or *functionally equivalent*).

But regardless of the answer to that question, the easiest solution is to simply use the exact same token sequence, which will be certain to be equivalent:

```
template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::bar() requires (isInt)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

However, current Clang releases don't accept any variations I try to name the static member, especially not those using the same token sequence in both declaration and definition. At least that last part is definitively a bug.

But on current Clang trunk all variations are accepted, indicating that this is a recently fixed bug.

Comment: Oh well. I tested it with Clang 14, Clang 15 and MSVC - lucky me :D Thanks for restoring my C++ sanity. GCC 12.2 can handle this correctly btw.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an MSVC bug. Here's a workaround:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <class T>
concept isInt = std::integral<T>;

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    void bar() requires (isInt<T>);
};

template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::bar() requires (isInt<T>) 
{
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/h6enoGqG6